# How connect the uploaded excel file using OLEDB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oledbconnection

I just want to check whether it's possible to connect to an Excel file I recently uploaded, here I'm using OLE DB. I wanted to check whether can I connect to that file properly or not and return a message. But when I try to connect to OLE DB it uploading the same file again. Can you help me with this problem

I'm using C# MVC and OLE DB 
I have already uploaded the file before checking its an excel file or not.

the controller for calling business and save file

```
if (_dataExchangeBusiness.IsExcelFile(fname)==true)
                    {                       
                        file.SaveAs(fname);
                        bool connectioncheck;
                        connectioncheck = _dataExchangeBusiness.CheckConnection(fname);
                        return Json(new { Result = "true", Message = "" });

                    }
                     else
                    {
                        return Json(new { Result = "false", Message = "" });
                    }
```

this is the business where the checking for excel file

```
 public bool IsExcelFile(string fname)
        {          
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(fname);
            try
            {
               if(extension== ".xls" || extension== ".xlsx")
                {                                       
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }           
        }
```

and here is the checking for OLE DB connection checking in business

```
   public bool CheckConnection(string fname)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(fname);
            try
            {
                string connstring = string.Empty;
                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls":
                        connstring = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString, fname);
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx":
                        connstring = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString, fname);
                        break;
                }
                OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
                try
                {
                    connExcel.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSchema;

                    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    // cmdExcel.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connExcel.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Here I'm expecting a result of true or false, that is whether can establish a connection or not

Comment: This line `connstring = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString, fname);` not including any Excel filename to pass into, therefore it always defaulted to filename predefined inside connection string in web.config. What is your actual problem then?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the **fname** include the file name

Comment: Assumed that the placeholder included in connection string - did you try `connExcel.Open()` and make a simple query to see if the connection is available?

Comment: yes `try
                {
                    connExcel.Open();
                    // cmdExcel.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connExcel.Close();
                }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public bool CheckConnection(string fname)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(fname);
            try
            {
                string connstring = string.Empty;
                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls":
                        connstring = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString, fname);
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx":
                        connstring = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString, fname);
                        break;
                }
                OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
                //bool canconnect = false;
                try
                {

                    connExcel.Open();
                    return true;
                    //DataTable dtExcelSchema;

                    //dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    // cmdExcel.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch 
                {
                    return false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connExcel.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

just return true after `connExcel.Open();` will get true if can connect else return false